# Error while installing hive in hadoop in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I got the following error after I installed hive in hadoop.

> Logging initialized using configuration in
>      jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
>         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)

I have tried alot but I am not able to get in hive terminal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to create new user for MySql. Follow this:

```
CREATE USER 'name_of_the_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'name_of_the_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'name_of_the_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'name_of_the_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```